# save() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am trying to save the current user in forms.py using save() method
can you please help me to solve this problem

here is my models.py
models.py

```
class Warden(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12 ,null=True)
    hostel_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default="logo-2.png",upload_to='users/', null=True, blank=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class HostelStaff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12 ,null=True)
    hostel_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #this is forignkey in which i want to save logged user
    warden = models.ForeignKey(Warden, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default="logo-2.png",upload_to='users/', null=True, blank=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName
```

this is my forms.py wher i overide save method
forms.py

```
class StaffSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_hostelstaff = True
        user.save()
        return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StaffSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' username'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' confirm password'
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        for fieldname in ['username','password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None


class StaffSignUpTwo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HostelStaff
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName','email', 'phone_number', 'hostel_name',)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StaffSignUpTwo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['firstName'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' first name'
        self.fields['lastName'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' last name'
        self.fields['hostel_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' hostel name'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' email'
        self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ' phone '
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, user):
        self.fields['user'] = user
        firstName = self.cleaned_data['firstName']
        lastName = self.cleaned_data['lastName']
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        hostel_name = self.cleaned_data['hostel_name']
        hostelstaff = HostelStaff.objects.create(user=user,  email=email,firstName=firstName,lastName=lastName,
                                       phone_number=phone_number,hostel_name=hostel_name)
        #here is save method 
        def save(self,pk,commit=True):
            obj = super().save(commit=False)
            #i think error in this line
            obj.warden=Warden.objects.get(user=self.user)
            obj.save()
            return obj
```

views.py

```
def StaffSignUpView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        main_form = StaffSignUpForm(request.POST)
        secondary_form = StaffSignUpTwo(request.user,request.POST)
        if main_form.is_valid() and secondary_form.is_valid():
            user = main_form.save()
            secondary_form.save(request.user)
            return redirect('warden_view:warden-home')
    else:
        main_form = StaffSignUpForm()
        secondary_form = StaffSignUpTwo(request.user)
    return render(request, 'warden_view/create_staff.html', {
        'main_form': main_form,
        'secondary_form': secondary_form
    })
```

[error scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CopWC.png)

save() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Django
save() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Django
save() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Djangosave() method in forms.py unable to save the foreignkey in Django

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the value for the object wrapped in the form with:

```
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, user):
        self.fields['user'] = user
        # …
```

But with:

```
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, user):
        self.instance.user = user
        # …
```

as for the `warden`, it looks like you wrapped this in a function *in* the `.save()` method. That is not a good idea either.

You furthermore create a `HostelStaff` object *in* the `save()` method of the form, which of course has no `warden` field.

```
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, user):
        self.instance.user = user
        self.instance.warden, __ = Warden.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return super().save()
```

I would however strongly advise against overriding the *signature* of the `save()` method, since class-based views, etc. often call these functions too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210127/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-save-method-in-forms-py-unable-to-sav).